# Number of normals to a parabola from a given point

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I know that from any point a maximum of three normals could be drawn to a parabola because the equation of normal is cubic. 
But I want to know the condition on the point for the number of normals

Comment: In two dimensions, there are only two normal vectors to a parabola at any given point. In three dimensions, there are infinitely many normal vectors to a parabola at any given point... Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: No buddy I'm talking about normals being drawn on a parabola from any point (not necessarily on the parabola)

Comment: I see. You mean to say "normals drawn from a parabola that contain a given point." Interesting query. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If the point is on the axis of the parabola you have three normals, everywhere else you have only two normals.

Comment: @N74 If the parabola is $y=x^2$ and the point on the normal is $(0,1/4)$, then what exactly are the three points on the parabola giving you three normals?

Comment: From that point three normals can't be drawn

Comment: @Palashgupta Correct - that's my point. :)

Comment: I have now learnt that the x coordinate of the point should be greater than twice the focal distance of the vertex in case of a horizontal parabola

Comment: And the y coordinate in case of a vertical parabola

Comment: @Palashgupta I think that Claude's answer is good. I'm going to upvote it. Do you have a problem with it?

Comment: Yup it seems good

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cubic Poynomial : In the equation $x^3 +3Hx +G=0$ if G and H are real and $G^2 +4H^3 &gt;0$ then roots of the.........](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565040/cubic-poynomial-in-the-equation-x3-3hx-g-0-if-g-and-h-are-real-and-g2)

Answer (score 11):

Claude's technique can be extended slightly to find the the points and normal lines given a particular point off of the parabola. Using this, I obtained an animation of some of the normals.

[image]

Comment: How can i draw such animation

Comment: Mclure How can i draw equation of three normal together.

Answer (score 7):

If $(p_x,p_y)$ are the coordinates of a point off the parabola and we'd like the line from $(p_x,p_y)$ to the point $(x,x^2)$ on the parabola to be normal to the parabola, then we need:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}p_x \\ p_y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x \\ x^2\end{pmatrix} + t \begin{pmatrix}-2x \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

This defines a pair of equation from which we
can eliminate $x$ to obtain a cubic in $t$:

$$
0 = 4t^3 - 4(p_y+1)t^2 + (4 p_y+1) t + p_x^2 - p_y = 0
$$

The [discriminant of a cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_discriminant) tells how many roots there are:

$$
0 = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\\
\Delta=18abcd-4b^{3}d+b^{2}c^{2}-4ac^{3}-27a^{2}d^{2}
$$

Then $\Delta > 0$ corresponds to 3 real roots, $\Delta < 0$ to 1 real root and 2 complex roots, and $\Delta = 0$ to multiple root with all roots real.

I don't know for the case $\Delta = 0$ whether there are two distinct roots (one with multiplicity 2) or one root with multiplicity 3.  Maybe both could occur.

I plotted the sign of the discriminant, with the parabola and a grid of unit size overlayed.  The grey regions correspond to positive discriminant (3 real roots), white regions to negative discriminant (1 real root).

[image: parabola normal count]

Here is the GLSL source code, for use with Fragmentarium:

```
#include "Progressive2D.frag"

vec3 color(vec2 p)
{
  float s = length(vec4(dFdx(p), dFdy(p)));
  if (p.y - s < p.x * p.x && p.x * p.x < p.y + s) return vec3(0.0);
  if (abs(mod(p.x + 0.5, 1.0) -0.5) < 0.5 * s) return vec3(0.5);
  if (abs(mod(p.y + 0.5, 1.0) -0.5) < 0.5 * s) return vec3(0.5);
  if ((abs(p.x) - s) * (abs(p.x) - s) < p.y &&
      p.y < (abs(p.x) + s) * (abs(p.x) + s)) return vec3(0.0);
  float a = 4.0;
  float b = -4.0 * (p.y + 1.0);
  float c = 4.0 * p.y + 1.0;
  float d = p.x * p.x - p.y;
  float discriminant
    = 18.0 * a * b * c * d
    - 4.0 * b * b * b * d
    + b * b * c * c
    - 4.0 * a * c * c * c
    - 27.0 * a * a * d * d;
  if (discriminant > 0.0) return vec3(0.7);
  if (discriminant < 0.0) return vec3(1.0);
                          return vec3(0.2);
}
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot but had to think the first bit through to follow it. I hope you don't mind my edit. Also, I believe that there's one normal at the cusp and two normals elsewhere. I'm going to post an answer illustrating what the normals look like

Comment: When you are on the boundary curve, called the **absolute** off the parabola, you could get either two roots with one doubly degenerate, or one trippy degenerate root.  The latter occurs when you choose the sharp tip or **cusp** of the evolute; elsewhere along that curve you get two roots with one doubly degenerate.  The degenerate normal in this latter case is always the one that crosses the axis.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: I don't know how either degeneracy or multiplicity works, so, dumbed-down, does your comment just mean that from all the points on the boundary of the evolute except the cusp, two normals can be drawn, and that from the cusp, it's only x=0 that's possible?

Comment: @harry that is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Only two perpendicular tangents can be drawn from a point P on a parabola directrix ( standard result, need not be again proved). Taking this as given we complete the rectangle by drawing parallels to arrive at a unique opposite point inside point Q ... from which we conclude accordingly only 2 unique normals can be drawn from an arbitrary but inside point like Q.

[image]

Comment: there is a third normal to the parabola (heading to the right) from your point marked Q, see https://mathr.co.uk/tmp/ZdYXF-mod.png its existence can be seen from the marked right hand normal crossing above Q, from the normal line moving below Q as x increases, and from the smoothness of the parabola

Comment: @Claude I have more carefully drawn it by Geogebra. Only two normals in this particular case.as at first stated, no third point.

Comment: @Narasinham your new diagram has $Q$ at around $(-0.7, -2.7)$, your old diagram had $Q$ at around $(-1.1, -3.7)$.

Comment: This is just wrong.

Comment: Agreed clearly wrong. I fail  to "properly" connect it to the third possibility, shall delete until it is found.

Comment: To find the extra normal, just do the circle that passes across the two already found feets plus the vertex of the parabola. It will cross across the extra feet. This diagram can be of some help https://www.geogebra.org/m/dfv9xyzb but of course the vertex is not one of the feets... usually.