# condition for three distinct normals to a parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have been looking for a condition to have three distinct normal to a parabola $y^2=4ax$ from a point $(h,k)$.

I found out the condition to be $ h>2a$. I understand that this is a necessary condition,  but this was not sufficient. So, I am searching for the extra condition.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533871/condition-for-3-distinct-normals-from-a-point-h-k-to-the-parabola-y2-4ax

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133724/number-of-normals-to-a-parabola-from-a-given-point?