# proof for that exactly one normal can be drawn to a parabola from an exterior point.

Tags: polynomials, conic-sections, cubics

It is well known that a maximum of three normals can be drawn from the interior of a parabola. But I am interested in the proof for the fact that exactly one normal can be drawn to a parabola from an **exterior** point wrt to the parabola.

---

So far I have done this.

WLOG we consider $y^2=4ax$.

Let the exterior point be $(h,k)$.

We must have $$k^2-4ah> 0\tag1$$

Also the equation of a normal to a parabola is $$y=mx-2am-am^3$$
so $(h,k)$ satisfies $$am^3+2am-mh+k=0$$

All I have to do is show that there is only one real root possible for this cubic using $(1)$.
Can anyone complete the proof?

---

Alternative methods are welcome!

**Note**By a normal i mean that a segment that is external to parabola

Thank you!

Comment: You can number equations using `\tag`.  See my edit.

Comment: @saulspatz i didn't know that thanks!

Comment: Look at the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Discriminant)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Several answers have pointed out that, under a strict reading, the statement we are asked to prove is actually false. Please clarify the question!

Comment: @BrianDrake  thanks! i have noted that please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

The question claims that exactly one normal can be drawn to a parabola from a point outside the parabola. This [is incorrect](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133724/number-of-normals-to-a-parabola-from-a-given-point).

Presumably the OP is imposing the restriction that the segment of the normal joining the point to the parabola must itself be outside the parabola. In this case, here is a proof not involving cubics:

WLOG, assume $a > 0$. Like in the question, let $(h, k)$ be a point outside the parabola.

Let $(x_p, y_p)$ be a point on the parabola. Consider the normal to the parabola at $(x_p, y_p)$; let $(x_n, y_n)$ be a point on the normal. We can divide the normal into two “rays”: one has $x_n > x_p$ and is (at least partly) inside the parabola; the other has $x_n < x_p$ and is outside the parabola. We are only interested in the second. From now on, we refer to this “ray” as the normal.

We also want the possibility that $(h, k)$ is on the normal, so we now require $x_p > h$.

Let $k'$ be the value of $y_n$ when $x_n = h$. That is, let $(h, k')$ be a point on the normal. Also let $m = -\frac{1}{2a}y_p$ be the gradient of the normal. Then

$$k' = y_p + m(h - x_p) = y_p(1 + \frac{1}{2a}(x_p - h))$$

so

$$|k'| = |y_p|(1 + \frac{1}{2a}(x_p - h))$$

is a continuous, strictly increasing, unbounded function of $|y_p|$ that takes on the value $|k|$ for exactly one value of $|y_p|$.

Since $k'$ has the same sign as $y_p$, $k'$ is a one-to-one function of $y_p$ that takes on the value $k$ for exactly one value of $y_p$.

This shows that exactly one normal contains the point $(h, k)$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

From the cubic

$$ax^3 +(2a-h)x +k =0$$

and using the conventions in [this paper](http://www.nickalls.org/dick/papers/maths/cubic1993.pdf), one has

$$\begin{align*} x_N &=0 \\
\\
\delta^2 &= \dfrac{h-2a}{3a} \\
\\
y_N &= k \\
\\
h' &= 2a\left(\dfrac{h-2a}{3a}\right)^\frac{3}{2}\\
\end{align*}$$

For simplicity and WLOG, assume $a >0$.

For the case of $h \le 2a$, then $\delta^2 \le 0$ and the cubic has no real turning points, and thus only 1 real root.

For the case of $h \gt 2a$, then $\delta^2 \gt 0$ and $h' \in \mathbb{R}$ and the cubic has two turning points.  In this case, to have only 1 real root, one needs to satisfy

$$\left|\dfrac{-y_N}{h'}\right| = \left|\dfrac{-k}{2a\left(\dfrac{h-2a}{3a}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\right| \gt 1$$

or equivalently

$$\begin{align*}\left|\dfrac{-k}{2a\left(\dfrac{h-2a}{3a}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\right|^2 &\gt 1^2\\
\\
k^2 &\gt 4a^2\left(\dfrac{h-2a}{3a}\right)^3\\
\\
k^2 - 4a\left[a\left(\dfrac{h-2a}{3a}\right)^3\right] &\gt 0 \\
\end{align*}$$

Now, to be consistent with the constraint in (1), one needs to show that

$$\begin{align*}a\left(\dfrac{h-2a}{3a}\right)^3 &\le h \\
\\
\left(h-2a\right)^3&\le 27a^2h \\
\end{align*}$$

which is certainly not true for $h \gg 2a$.

Therefore, it appears the constraint in (1) is not sufficient to guarantee that there is only one real root for $h \gg 2a$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if by normal you mean any line that intersects the parabola at 90 degrees then this is not true: take any point with positive $x$ on $y=x^2$ and draw a normal line $l$ at $(x, x^2)$. It will  intersect the part of the parabola with negative $x$s somewhere, say at $(x_n, x_n^2)$. Then any point to the left of that  $(x_n, x_n^2)$ will have a normal which intersects $l$ at a point $p$ external to the parabola. This $p$ has two "normals" to the parabola. (This is why purely algebraic arguments that find such normal lines will not give uniqueness.) However, if by normal you mean a segment that is entirely external to the parabola, then this is true for the exterior of any closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ - hence for the exterior of the graph of any convex function (more precisely, for the "overgraph" $S=\{(\vec{x}, y)| y\geq f(\vec{x})\}$ for any convex function $f$), including of course the parabola  $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

Let's show this. Firstly, for any closed convex set $S$ and for any point $p$ not in $S$ there exists unique point $n$ in $S$ which is closest to $p$. This $n$ will lie on the boundary and, when the boundary is differentiable $np$ will be normal to it (see below for a proof of all of this). Moreover, since there are no points of $S$ closer to $p$ than $n$, the whole segment $np$ lies outside of $S$.

Now, why doesn't there exist a second normal segment? Suppose there is one, say $pn'$. Then the normal $T_{n'}$ to $pn'$ through $n'$ is tangent  to the boundary of $S$ at $n'$.  By convexity of $S$, $S$ lies on one side of this tangent $T_{n'}$. Since the segment $pn'$ is outside $S$, we must have $S$ on the opposite side of $T_{n'}$ from $p$. But then $n$ is on the opposite side of $T_{n'}$ from $p$, and in particular is further from $p$ than $n'$, which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.

---

Now, for completeness, the existence of the closest point and it's normality:

**Existence of the closest point**: Pick a point $s\in S$ let $S_b=S\cap B(p, |p, s|)$ be the intersection of $S$ with closed ball around $p$. Now $S_b$ is closed and bounded, so the distance function to $p$ being continuous has a minimum on $S_b$. Suppose this minimum is $m$ and is achieved at $n\in S_b$. Now any other point in $S$ is either not in $S_b$, and so has distance to $p$ bigger than $|p-s|$ and so also bigger than $|p-n|$, or is in $S_b$ and so has distance to $p$ at least $|p-n|$. We conclude that $n$ is a point at which the minimum distance from $p$ to $S$ is achieved.

**The closest point is on the boundary**: Draw the segment $pn$. If $n$ is in the interior of $S$ there would be other points of the segment that lie in $S$; but then they would be closer to $p$ than $n$, which is impossible. So $n$ is on the boundary.

**Uniqueness of the closest point**: Draw the tangent  $T_n$ to $S$ at $n$ (in general, "a support hyperplane"). Then all of $S$ is on one side of $T_n$ by convexity, and it is the opposite side from $p$ (otherwise some point $s' \in S$ is on the same side of $T_n$ as $p$ then, by convexity os $S$, the segment $s'n$ is in $S$, but for points on that segment close to $n$ the distance to $p$ is smaller than that of $n$, which is a contradiction). But all points on opposite side of $T_n$ from $p$ have higher distance to $p$ than $n$ -- and, in particular, all points of $S$ do. Thus $n$ is the unique point of $S$ closest to $p$.

**Normality of the closest point**: Now assuming  the boundary   $\partial S$ is differentiable, let's see why $pn$ is normal to $\partial S$.  If $np$ is not normal to $\gamma$ at $n$, then the tangent $T_n$ of $\partial S$ at $n$ has points very near $n$ that are closer to $p$ than $n$; but then since near $n$ the $\partial S$ itself follows the tangent closely, there will be points of $\partial S \subset S$ that are closer to $p$ than $n$, which is not true. So $pn$ is orthogonal to $\partial S$ as wanted.